# Command mode does not work

Tags: command-line

Entering a command via the keyboard on the console it is only possible to enter text until a command is recognized.

If you want to enter `sudo adduser Fritz admin` after entering `sudo` no more input ist possible.

Both consoles Terminal and LXTerminal show the same behaviour.
I think this error is due to the updates in the last two months. Before the console mode worked properly.

This is in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. What can I do?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can't you type anything after `sudo ` or can't you use <TAB> to do command expansion ?

Comment: It is possible to type all letters
          e.g. :     sudofritzen
But when typing a Space the terminal window  will be moved to the center of the screen. When clicking on the window with the mouse, the window will be moved to the place before. Than it is possible to enter more letters.
When finishing this input with enter,  the system reacts as requested. However it is not possible to specify the parameters for a command.

Answer (score 0):

Playing around I found a solution as follows:

instead of Space as separation for command and parameters you have to type in AltGr + Space.
That is very easy, but if you dont know it, it is a big problem.